# javafx. Доступ к контроллеру

Tags: javafx

У меня есть главный Node start.fxml с меню и со своим контроллером.
В зависимости от выбранного пункта меню, в нем отображаются вложенные Node со своей информацией и своим контроллером.
Для наглядности:

**StartView.java**

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
...
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("start.fxml"));
primaryStage.show();
...
}
```

**StartController.java**

```
...
@FXML
public void menuItem1() {
...
node = (Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Modules/module1.fxml"));
ancorPaneMainFrame.getChildren().setAll(node);
...
}

@FXML
public void menuItem2() {
...
node = (Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Modules/module2.fxml"));
ancorPaneMainFrame.getChildren().setAll(node);
...
}

@FXML
public void saveAs() {

// здесь нужен доступ к полю objectList контроллера Module1Controller
}
```

**Module1View.java**

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
...
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("start.fxml"));
primaryStage.show();
...
}
```

**Module1Controller.java**

```
...
public List<Object> objectList;
...
```

Я не могу понять, как мне из метода saveAs получить доступ к полю objectList ?

а еще лучше, из метода saveAs получить доступ к какому нибудь методу контроллера Module1Controller.java

Comment: `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( ... ); loader.load(); controller = loader.getController(); controller.doSomething();`

Comment: или `controller = new MyController(/*...*/); loader.setController( controller ); loader.load(); controller.doSomething();`

Comment: Но ведь оба способа создадут новый объект контроллера. А мне нужно получить доступ к существующему объекту...

Comment: Более того, у меня несколько различных контроллеров и из метода saveAs нужно понять какой из них активный.

Comment: `getController()` не создаст новый объект. Различным контроллерам можно дать один интерфейс и присохронять активный в полях класса. Если я правильно понял, то методы `menuItemN()` это `onAction` из fxml и мне кажется странным каждый раз создавать новое view с контоллером, хотя могу ошибаться.

Comment: Я вышел из положения очень похоже.
Всем контроллерам создал класс-родитель и сохранял активный в поле класса.
В данном случае каждое view уникально, поэтому под него мне было проще создать свой контроллер )